# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: method error without journal_mode iOS 9

Tags: core-data, ios9, persistent, journal

I am checking my app with iOS9.

A problem happens when I try to reset the database.

See the below code: (Its in `AppDelegate`)

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
   if(persistentStoreCoordinator == nil)
   {
       ....
       ....
       persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

       [persistentStoreCoordinator lock];

        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
        {     
        }

        [persistentStoreCoordinator unlock];
   }

   return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Here, the options are..

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,nil];
```

This code works fine with iOS8 and below. But when I run it with iOS9, 
the following exception happens.

> CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite
>   configuration:(null)
>   URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/….*.sqlite
>   options:{  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1; 
>   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;  } ... returned
>   error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=522 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/…*.sqlite. SQLite error
>   code:522, 'not an error', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=522} with userInfo
>   dictionary {  NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 522;  NSUnderlyingException = "I/O
>   error for database at
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/….*.sqlite. SQLite error
>   code:522, 'not an error'";  }

But if I add the key-value pair as `"journal_mode" = "MEMORY"` in my existing "*options*" dictionary, this error was not happening.

**Question:**

What does "journal_mode" means in options dictionary? Is it the real problem in my case?

Comment: It is happening to me too! did the journal_mode add any other collateral issue?

Comment: In my case I found that iOS9 creates 2 more files, when deleting the DB I had to delete them all to make it work

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol: can you show some code please?

Comment: @Grace here you have : http://pastebin.com/Qx4mvUuc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't have enough reputation points to comment on your post. But most of what you need to know about `journal_mode` can be found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode).

If my opinion counts, I would never use `MEMORY`, it just scares me.

I would recommend either `DELETE` or `WAN`. Both of these remove the errors that you're seeing and seem much safer to use rather than using `MEMORY`.